# Is it possible to perform a SQL Injection on a application that uses Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-injection

Can [Entity Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework) be hacked?

> Is it possible to perform a **SQL Injection** on a application that uses EF?

If so, can someone please provide a full example of how that might be done? I couldn't find any specific to EF in C#.

Comment: It is quite easily possible if the developer uses EF as a wrapper around ADO.NET and uses `FromSQL`. Of course, this is not the intended nor normal use of EF, but I have seen it

Comment: [Security Considerations (Entity Framework)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heed this:

> It is quite easily possible if the developer uses EF as a wrapper
>   around ADO.NET and uses FromSQL. Of course, this is not the intended
>   nor normal use of EF, but I have seen it – Camilo Terevinto

REF: [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

---

Additionally, while not really "sql injection", since one of the goals of such is to somewhat alter your data by altering your raw sql to produce some unintended result, you should also be aware of [ASP.NET - **Overposting**/Mass Assignment Model Binding Security](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETOverpostingMassAssignmentModelBindingSecurity.aspx)

Sample taken straight from link:

You model/class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Somewhere in your `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(person);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(person);
}
```

> If a theoretical EvilUser found out that Person had an "IsAdmin"
>   property, they could "overpost" and add a field to the HTTP POST and
>   set `IsAdmin=true`. **There's nothing in the code here to prevent that**.

So "evil user" doesn't even need to figure out `sql injection` to do some unintended result. Read up on the article on ways to prevent it (e.g. `BindAttribute`, View Models).

Hth.

Comment: I don't think `IsAdmin` hijack is same as SQL Injection, it is purely lack of business logic validation failure and lack of concurrency control, xss etc.

Comment: @AkashKava Like I said, _"it's not really sql injection"_. End of day, it accomplishes some of what sql injection can/would or "hacked" as OP asks...

Answer (score 3):

Depends on of the use of it. 
If you use LINQ yes, it´s safe against SQL INJECTION because it passes all data to the database via SQL parameters. LINQ queries are not composed by using string manipulation or concatenation, that's why they are not susceptible to traditional SQL injection attacks.